# How do I fix an app that's stuck in application switcher?

Tags: macos, application-switcher

I'm running OS X 10.7.5 "Lion". Three times now, Preview.app has gotten in a state where its icon is visible in the application switcher (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) but it isn't running (doesn't show up in `ps ax` in the Terminal) and will not start (e.g. double-clicking a PDF document).

I've tried `killall Dock`, `killall SystemUIServer`, and `killall Finder` and those do restart but the stuck Preview icon is still in the application switcher. I've also tried removing the saved state under Library > Containers > com.apple.Preview but that doesn't work either. The only thing that solves it is logging out and back in again.

Is there some way to get this unstuck without having to log out?

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same thing in Yosemite beta :-/

Answer (score 2):

In `Terminal.app`, find the process ID for Dock with the `ps aux | grep Dock` command and kill it with the `kill -9 PID` command. An example:

```
$ ps aux | grep Dock
username              290   0.0  0.4  2730344  34500   ??  S    Fri08PM   0:22.48 /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/MacOS/Dock
username             3633   0.0  0.0  2432784    612 s000  S+    8:06PM   0:00.00 grep Dock
$ kill -9 290
```

Comment: This is basically the same as "killall Dock", which doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks! Works on Mac OS 10.9.4. Don't forget to use sudo, this way `sudo ps aux | grep Dock`, look for Dock app PID and use `sudo kill -9 PID`